# Stop Firebase downloading task returned by GetFileAsync in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, mono, firebase-storage

I met a case when I need to stop already started downloading task using GetFileAsync method. Unfortunately I didn't find any info about it and how to implement it in Unity3D (c#). 
I know there is a way to stop thread, but don't see the way to find thread by that task.

The idea is to stop downloading in some cases, for example if user change the scene and downloading content is not actual anymore.

Please, advice, is there a solution to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the download methods all return a C# [`Task`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/system/threading/tasks/task#class_system_1_1_threading_1_1_tasks_1_1_task), which doesn't contain a pause or similar method, I don't think there's a way to do this at present.

Comment: Must be a method inside Firebase SDK or may be getting the thread, where tasks are running